# Google Sheets - QUERY a range using another range of criteria

Tags: google-sheets

I want to query a range of data while using another range of data as the criteria without manually inputting each criteria.

If I have the dataset in this image: [image]

I want to select `Age` where `Name` matches any of the names under `Criteria`;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by utilizing the `MATCHES` feature of the `QUERY` function, which will match via a regular expression [Reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#where). To do this, you will need to `JOIN` each of the cells together like this:

```
=JOIN("|",D2:D6)
```

This will give you a string concatenated with a pipe symbol`|`, which acts as an `or` like operator matching `John` or `Brock` or `Rachel`...etc :

```
John|Brock|Rachel|Amanda|Jennifer
```

You can use this inside of your query like so:

```
=QUERY(A2:B8, "SELECT B WHERE A MATCHES '"&JOIN("|",D2:D6)&"'")
```

Comment: Would it be hard to add functionality based on the `QUERY` in this sense?

Answer (score 0):

thanks so much for the answer Douglas, just in case you do not have the complete list filled out under the "criteria" column, you could do:

```
=QUERY(A2:B8, "SELECT B WHERE A MATCHES '"&JOIN("|",UNIQUE(D2:D6))&"'")
```